# How can I only give text to a label once a data request is complete?

Tags: ios, swift

I tried using a closure since it seemed like the obvious choice but I'm still having a problem with this. Basically I have the user login with Facebook, and once they have an access token, their data is fetched (just name and email). I have two labels in my view that I want to display their name and email.

EDIT: After Matt's suggestion:

```
// Get user info
func getUserInfo(finished: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let params = ["fields" : "email, name"]
    let graphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params)
    graphRequest.start {
        (urlResponse, requestResult) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

        switch requestResult {
        case .failed(let error):
            print("error in graph request:", error)
            break
        case .success(let graphResponse):
            if let responseDictionary = graphResponse.dictionaryValue {
                print(responseDictionary)

                if let name = responseDictionary["name"] {
                    self.nameLabel.text = "Logged in as: \n\(name)"
                }

                if let email = responseDictionary["email"] {
                    self.emailLabel.text = "Your email is: \n\(email)"
                } else {
                    self.emailLabel.text = "Your email is: "
                }
                print(responseDictionary["name"])
                print(responseDictionary["email"])
            }
        }
            finished()
        }

    }

}
```

And in `viewDidLoad`

```
    if AccessToken.current != nil {
        getUserInfo {
            self.view.addSubview(self.emailLabel)
            self.view.addSubview(self.nameLabel)
            self.setupNameLabel()
            self.setupEmailLabel()
        }

    }
```

Initializing the labels

```
let emailLabel: UILabel = {
    let frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 400, height: 200)
    let label = UILabel(frame: frame)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    label.text = ""
    label.numberOfLines = 2
    label.textColor = UIColor.black
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return label
}()

let nameLabel: UILabel = {
    let frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 400, height: 200)
    let nLabel = UILabel(frame: frame)
    nLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    nLabel.text = ""
    nLabel.numberOfLines = 2
    nLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    nLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return nLabel
}()
```

Constraints for the labels

```
func setupEmailLabel() {
    emailLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    emailLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    emailLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    emailLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 73).isActive = true
}

func setupNameLabel() {
    nameLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: facebookShareButton.topAnchor, constant: -230).isActive = true
    nameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    nameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 73).isActive = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problems with what you're doing are:

1. that you are not calling `finished()` in the completion handler, and
2. that you are failing to make sure you're on the main thread.

So, it's easy to fix. You have this:

```
graphRequest.start {
    (urlResponse, requestResult) in
    // ... your stuff (switch statement)
}
finished()
```

Change it to this:

```
graphRequest.start {
    (urlResponse, requestResult) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // ... your stuff (switch statement)
        finished()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks matt! I tried this but the labels aren't showing up. Probably an error on my part, but I edited my question with the code I tried if you can see where I went wrong? Xcode suggested I add @escaping, which then threw me errors on the labels so I had to add self to all of them.

Comment: The "labels aren't showing up" could depend on lots of stuff you have not shown. I don't know how `self.nameLabel` is initialized, I don't know whether the  "if let" tests are passing and setting the `text`, I don't know what `self.setupNameLabel()` does, I don't even know whether `getUserInfo` is being _called_. Only _you_ know that. But _that is not what you asked_. The question was how to set the label's text only after the request was complete and I answered that.